# phpmyadmin gives fatal error: The Navigation can only be accessed via Ajax

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost

I opened PhpMyadmin and tried to navigate to the databases. When I tried to go to the other pages of databases in PhpMyadmin, it gave me this error (fatal error: The Navigation can only be accessed via Ajax).[image: PhpMyadmin Error Image]. Now its working again. I'm just curious what might have caused this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not open links in new tab. Clicking on link will make the desired result.